# VBA for Excel - building .Formula with contents containing quotation marks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm coding a project in VBA for Excel, which loops to a file, matches the 'code' for each of the quantities, and then feeds all the matches for that code to a user defined function, which goes onto the Excel sheet.

I can read the info, sort it so postdata(nr_of_datafield, nr_of_item) returns me the row in the source sheet on which the value is listed. Based on this, I need to create (through .Formula) a syntax like this:

=formul(raming!J104) (if there's only one occurence)
=formul(raming!J104;"+";raming!J108) (etc., always adding the same extra if there's multiple occurences)
=formul(raming!J104;"+";raming!J108;"+";raming!312;"+";raming!J403) etcetera, with always needing to get the previous values from what's already in Cells.Formula.

Based on this check:

Code:

```
Right(Workbooks(meetstaatfile).Sheets("HOR_raming").Cells(lusteller12, 9 + CInt(postdata(3, eerstepositie)) * 3).Formula, 2) = "()"
```

I can detect if there is already any contents added here. If not (meaning the check for () ending is positive), I replace with this:

Code:

```
Workbooks(meetstaatfile).Sheets("HOR_raming").Cells(lusteller12, 9 + postdata(3, eerstepositie) * 3).Formula = "=formul('raming'!J" & postdata(2, eerstepositie) & ")"
```

To create a formula that looks like: =formul(raming!J104)

(the '104' in this example is the output from postdata(2,eerstepositie)

However, if it doesn't trigger for the () ending, there already is a value, and I need to extend the formula to something like this: =formul(raming!J104;"+";raming!J108)

I've been trying to figure out how to do this by replacing ')' with the block I want added, but I cannot get it to work to input the quotation marks. ('formul' is very similar to concatenating text).

**How can I make a variation of the codeline above that lets me alter the cell input? Either by a Replace() like I was trying, or reading what's between the formul() brackets and rebuilding the formula?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have quotation marks as content within a string literal in VBA, you have to double them. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234766.aspx

```
.Formula = "=formul('raming'!J" & 104 & ",""+""," & "'raming'!J" & 108 & ")"
```

Or with your postdata:

```
.Formula = "=formul('raming'!J" & postdata(2, eerstepositie) & ",""+""," & "'raming'!J" & postdata(2, whatevergets108)  & ")"
```

I don't know, whether I have understood it right, but if you need to concatenate the formula in dependence of the contents of an array, then this can be achieved like so:

```
Sub test()
 'one occurrence
 postdata = [{0;104}]
 sFormulaString = getFormulaString(postdata, 2)
 MsgBox sFormulaString
 'two occurrences
 postdata = [{0,0;104,108}]
 sFormulaString = getFormulaString(postdata, 2)
 MsgBox sFormulaString
 'three occurrences
 postdata = [{0,0,0;104,108,312}]
 sFormulaString = getFormulaString(postdata, 2)
 MsgBox sFormulaString
End Sub

Function getFormulaString(postdata As Variant, nr_of_datafield As Long) As String
 sFormula = "=formul("
 For i = LBound(postdata, 2) To UBound(postdata, 2)
  sFormula = sFormula & "'raming'!J" & postdata(nr_of_datafield, i) & ",""+"","
 Next
 sFormula = Left(sFormula, Len(sFormula) - 5) & ")"
 getFormulaString = sFormula
End Function
```

Hm, or is the real need, to append new formula parts into an existing formula? If so, the following code will append a new part into the Formula in A1 every time it runs.

```
Sub test2()

 postdata = [{0;104}]

 sFormula = Range("A1").Formula
 If sFormula = "" Then sFormula = "=formul("
 If Right(sFormula, 1) = ")" Then sFormula = Left(sFormula, Len(sFormula) - 1) & ",""+"","
 sFormula = sFormula & "'raming'!J" & postdata(2, 1) & ")"
 Range("A1").Formula = sFormula

End Sub
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. That indeed works, but the problem is: I cannot build it like that, as I don't know ahead of time how many element I'll encounter that need to go in there. So basically, I could have a 4th term to add to the formula, while having to read what the previous three were from what's already in cells().formula.

Edited topic to explain that particular issue.

Comment: As for your addition to the answer, i indeed needed to append to the formula each time, finally managed to get it to work thanks to your help. Accepted the answer. (indeed, cutting away the last ')' rather then replacing it was probably the smarter idea.